# Gulp-connect with Express server?

Tags: node.js, express, gulp, gulp-connect

How to configure `gulp-connect` to run file at `bin/www` (express)? I can't make it work, I find no documentation on gulp-connect site that deal with config/change the starting file used by `gulp-connect`.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
connect = require('gulp-connect');

gulp.task('webserver', function() {
    connect.server({
        root: 'app',
        livereload: true
    });
});

gulp.task('default', ['webserver']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are using you using both "Express" and "gulp-connect" ?

You should just stick to one.
Assign `root : bin/www` and it should work or `root: [__dirname]`

Alternatively use:

`path = require('path')` and then `root: path.resolve('./')`